# How to download and show a list of images in a collection view so to avoid flickering and images in wrong spots?

Tags: swift, image, uicollectionview, lazy-loading

I'm struggling to solve the very common problem of loading images inside a collection view given a list of urls. I have implemented a `UIImageView` extension. In there I defined a cache variable:

```
static var imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
```

In addition I have created a `loadImage` method that takes as input the image cache key, the url itself, a placeholder image and an error image and works as follows:

```
public func loadImage(cacheKey: String?, urlString: String?, placeholderImage: UIImage?, errorImage: UIImage?) {
    
    image = nil
    
    if let cacheKey = cacheKey, let cachedImage = UIImageView.imageCache.object(forKey: cacheKey as NSString) {
        image = cachedImage
        return
    }
    
    if let placeholder = placeholderImage {
        image = placeholder
    }
    
    if let urlString = urlString, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        self.downloadImage(url: url, errorImage: errorImage)
    } else {
        image = errorImage
    }
}
```

The download image function proceeds to create a data task, download the image and assign to the image view:

```
private func downloadImage(url: URL, errorImage: UIImage?) {
    
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] (data, response, error ) in
        
        if error != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.image = errorImage
            }
            return
        }
        
        if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
            if !(200...299).contains(statusCode) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.image = errorImage
                }
                return
            }
        }
        
        if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            UIImageView.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.image = image
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    dataTask.resume()
    
}
```

I call the `loadImage` method inside `cellForItemAt`, so that I don't have to download all the data at once, but only the images that are effectively displayed on screen. The way I call the function is the following:

```
cell.albumImage.loadImage(
    cacheKey: bestQualityImage,
    urlString: bestQualityImage,
    placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Undefined"),
    errorImage: UIImage(named: "Undefined")
)
```

The main problem I face with the current implementation is that sometimes the images are not displayed in the correct spot. In other words, if I have three elements on screen I would sometimes see all three elements with the same image instead of their respective image.

I believe that the problem is that by the time the download is complete for a specific cell, the cellForItemAt for that cell has already ended and the cell gets the wrong image instead.

Is there a way I can modify my function to fix this bug or should I completely change my approach?

EDIT.
At the beginning I thought the problem was that I was using an extension and I tried to use a function with a closure returning the downloaded image but that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a custom UICollectionView cell ? Perhaps try adding the override for `prepareForReuse()` in your custom cell implementation and set the image to nil in this function.

Comment: You can look how does `SDWebImage`/`Alamofire+Image`/`KingFisher`, they usually use `getAssociatedObject()` to set an additional property to the image, usually the `URL`, and when downloaded, if the URL doesn't match, don't apply the image, because cell has been reused before the download has finished. In KingFisher, it's `taskIdentifier`, in SDWebImage, it's `sd_imageURL`, etc. Easiest way is to use their library instead of reimplementing it yourself.

Comment: @Larme I didn't want to add an additional dependency in my project for something that should be simple to do, but maybe you're right. I'll try SDWebImage. That should fix my issue.