# Media Stack Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, api

Im using Media Stack API and when I try and get the image for each article I get repeat images for different articles and it would be multiple images that have duplicates. I am not sure why this is happening.

```
//MARK: - URLImageView
 extension UIImageView {
// Updating image view from URL
func load(url: URL) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: There shouldn't be. Are you using a `UICollectionView` or a `UITableView`? Could the issue be related to the reuse concept of their cells?

Comment: @Larme Im using UITableView

Comment: Do you know that cells are reused? You might want to use `SDWebImage`, `KingFisher` or `Alamofire+Image` instead. It's the same issue as stated their: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70721225/how-to-download-and-show-a-list-of-images-in-a-collection-view-so-to-avoid-flick#comment125023524_70721225 I gave solution on what to look if needed if you still want to do it yourself.